# Create to a folder under /sdcard/Download folder in Android API 29 and API 30

Tags: android

I use this code to make a folder under /sdcard/Download

```
String toLocation = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + 
                + "/MyFolder/example.txt";
File toLocationFile = new File(toLocation);

if (!toLocationFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
    toLocationFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
```

The build is targeted to API 30. The code can create folder "MyFolder" in Android 11 device but can't in Android 10 device.

Why does the same call get different result?

Notes:

Not set requestLegacyExternalStorage = true in AndroidManifest; means I am using scoped storage.

No write permission.

Comment: Is it a bug that Android 11 allows the folder to be created, even without any storage permission,  to use neither Storage Access Framework nor the DownloadManager? How can Android 11 enforce scoped storage if this code work?

Comment: App with targetSdkVersion 30 and no requestLegacyExternalStorage flag is able to create folders under Documents and Download directory but throws FileSystemException when creating a folder under the root storage directory "/storage/emulated/0". Is this the expected behavior of "Scoped Storage" in API Level 30? Why then use MediaStoreAPI?

Answer (score 3):

In an Android 11 device you do not need any permission to create that folder.

For an Android 10 device add requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" or use Storage Access Framework or the DownloadManager.

Comment: scoped storage is introduced from Android 10 and enforced from Android 11. My build is targeted to Android API 30. It should work the same when the code is running on either Android 10 or 11, right? why does Android 11 device not request to use Storage Access Framework or the DownloadManager.?

Comment: `It should work the same when the code is running on either Android 10 or 11, right?` Why? And apparently that is not the case. Only Google knows why.

Comment: With Target SDK 30, on Android 11 device it works without requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", but is required for Android 10 device. "requestLegacyExternalStorage" will be ignored ONLY on Android 11? Does that mean even if playstore forces API Level to be 30 from November 2021,  Android 10 and lower devices can still use the Leagcy Storage?

Comment: `"requestLegacyExternalStorage" will be ignored ONLY on Android 11?` I said and would say: ` "requestLegacyExternalStorage" only has effect on an Android 10 device.`

Comment: @PawanJain yes, google can't change devices already out there. All they do is force us to target the newest release if we want to list on the playstore.  you are allowed, for instance to write code that would only work on android kit-kit, so long as your app has a work-around for android 11, or just has less functionality under the newest release.